# Is Traversable different for breadth-first and depth-first trees?

Tags: haskell, tree, traversable

I have a Rose Tree structure and I wanted to write a [`Traversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Traversable.html) instance for it. So I started with the following:

```hs
data Tree a = Tree a [Tree a] deriving (Show)

instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f (Tree x subs) = Tree (f x) (fmap (fmap f) subs)
```

I did the depth-first variant of it:

```hs
newtype Depth a = Depth (Tree a) deriving (Show)

depth :: Tree a -> [a]
depth (Tree x subs) = x : concatMap depth subs

instance Functor Depth where
  fmap f (Depth t) = Depth $ fmap f t

instance Foldable Depth where
  foldMap f (Depth t) = mconcat $ f <$> depth t

instance Traversable Depth where
  traverse f (Depth t) = Depth <$> go t
    where go (Tree x subs) = Tree <$> f x <*> traverse go subs
```

Then I tried the breadth-first variant:

```hs
newtype Breadth a = Breadth (Tree a) deriving (Show)

breadth :: Tree a -> [a]
breadth tree = go [tree]
  where
    go [] = []
    go (Tree x subs:q) = x : go (q <> subs)

instance Functor Breadth where
  fmap f (Breadth t) = Breadth $ fmap f t

instance Foldable Breadth where
  foldMap f (Breadth t) = mconcat $ f <$> breadth t

instance Traversable Breadth where
  traverse f (Breadth t) = ???
```

And I realized that the breadth and depth first variants of `Traversable` for this should be the same. Is this the case? I don't believe I've actually read this anywhere but traversal is independent of the order of the elements?

If so, this gets a little weird because `Traversable` can then be implemented directly for `Tree`, which means that `Foldable` needs to be implemented for `Tree`, but there are obviously multiple ways that `Foldable` can be implemented.

Comment: You can definitely do the effects of the traversal in a different order for the two. Although it might be a bit tricky to reconstruct the tree at the end! It should definitely be possible, though.

Answer (score 8):

`Traversable` has to agree with `Foldable`. Specifically, if `Monoid m`, then `Applicative (Const m)`, causing a consistency law `foldMap f = getConst . traverse (Const . f)`. It is thus *impossible* for `Breadth` and `Depth` to share a `Traversable`. There is either a different implementation for `Traversable Breadth` that agrees with its `Foldable`, or there is none at all. I can cook up an implementation that I believe does agree, but I haven't verified the other laws.

```
instance Traversable Breadth where
  traverse f (Breadth t) = Breadth <$> head <$> go [t]
    where
      go [] = pure []
      go ts = zipWith Tree <$> traverse f rs
                           <*> (fmap (rebuild css) $ go $ concat css)
        where
          (rs, css) = unzip $ map (\(Tree r cs) -> (r, cs)) ts
          -- rebuild s d = evalState (traverse (state splitAt') d) s
          -- I think, but let's keep the dependencies down, shall we?
          rebuild [] [] = []
          rebuild (struct : structs) destruct
            = let (cs, destruct') = splitAt' struct destruct
              in  cs : rebuild structs destruct'
          -- ignoring the as in a [a] makes it look like a number
          splitAt' [] xs = ([], xs)
          splitAt' (_ : n) (x : xs)
            = let (pre, suf) = splitAt' n xs
              in  (x : pre, suf)
```

This is pretty hairy, and there's non-totality everywhere, but it should work out fine.

Comment: What I mean is that the output of `Traversable` for both `Depth` and `Breadth` should be the same shouldn't it? It simply processes the elements in a different order.

Comment: Absolutely not! `traverse` turns a collection of actions producing values into an action producing a collection of values. The order in which the actions are executed changes from `Depth` to `Breadth`, so the values they produce may change or the actions they execute may change. E.g. `traverse print` and `traverse (const $ get <* modify (+1))`. Heck: `depth = getConst . traverse (Const . return) . Depth` and `breadth = getConst . traverse (Const . return) . Breadth`

Comment: @Listerone though you are correct that `traverse` will be the same if you use it on an Applicative which is order independent such as `Identity` or `(r ->)`.  But in general the order of effects absolutely matters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation of HTNW's solution, using `Compose` instead of flattening the structure on recursive call. This means we don't need to rebuild the structure, but it is probably also slower, since it requires traversing a deep structure at every recursive step.

`liftA2` together with a `ZipList` is used to generalize `zipWith` to arbitrary many `Compose`d nested lists. The `ScopedTypeVariables` is needed to give an explicit type signature to the polymorphically recursive function `go`.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module BreadthFirstTraverse where
import Data.Tree (Tree(..))
import Control.Applicative (ZipList(..), Applicative (liftA2))
import Data.Functor.Compose (Compose(..))
-- import Control.Monad.Identity (Identity(..))

-- ...

instance Traversable Breadth where
  traverse f (Breadth t) = Breadth <$> bfTraverse f t

bfTraverse :: forall f a b. Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> Tree a -> f (Tree b)
bfTraverse k (Node t0 ts0) = nodeC <$> k t0 <*> go (ZipList ts0)
-- equivalent alternative: 
-- bfTraverse k t = fmap runIdentity (go (Identity t))
  where
    nodeC x xs = Node x (getZipList xs)
    go :: (Applicative t, Traversable t) => t (Tree a) -> f (t (Tree b))
    go ts | Just ts' <- nullMap ts = pure ts'
    go ts = liftA2 nodeC <$> traverse k rs <*> fmap getCompose (go $ Compose css)
        where
          rs = fmap rootLabel ts
          css = fmap (ZipList . subForest) ts

-- | If a structure is empty, replace its content type
-- > isJust . nullMap == null
nullMap :: Traversable t => t a -> Maybe (t b)
nullMap = traverse (const Nothing)
```